# C# Func<> Delegate property setter issue

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I am trying to return an object of type **IDocumentTemplateProvider** using a delegate as below:

```
public static class DocumentTemplateProvider
{
    private static Func<IDocumentTemplateProvider> _docTemplateProvider;

    public static void SetdocTemplateProvider(Func<IDocumentTemplateProvider> docTemplateProvider)
    {
        _docTemplateProvider = docTemplateProvider;
    }

    public static void SetDocTemplateProvider<T>() where T : IDocumentTemplateProvider, new()
    {
        _docTemplateProvider = () => new T();
    }

    public static IDocumentTemplateProvider TemplateProvider
    {
        get { return _docTemplateProvider(); }
    }
}
```

However when I'm calling it using:

```
private static readonly IDocumentTemplateProvider _template = DocumentTemplateProvider.TemplateProvider;
```

**_template** is always null. I'm fairly new to C# Func<> delegates so i can't bloody see what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

### UPDATE: To clear ant confusion i've added the full code where _template is initialized and used as is:

```
 public class DocumentModule : IHttpModule
{
        private static readonly IDocumentTemplateProvider _template = DocumentTemplateProvider.TemplateProvider;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
            context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
        }      

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
            context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
        }

        private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _template.SetProvider();
        }

        private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _template.Finalize();
        }        

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: You're setting `_template` to `DocumentTemplateProvider.TemplateProvider` which is a property which returns `_docTemplateProvider`, which is never set as far as we can see?

Comment: @Blorgbeard OP should be getting NRE if it is the case as `TemplateProvider` invokes method, not just returns it. Clearly incomplete code is shown significantly limiting chance of answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that's all i have - there is no omitted code from the DocumentTemplateProvider class!

Comment: Hmm... I'm confused... if that would be part of method you should be getting NRE, the way you show now (`static readonly` field) it should cause exception during type instantiation and that type should be dead... Definitely interesting, also absolutely not practical question (I assume you really not planning to write code that relies on random order of static initialization).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've update the question with full code.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post. Unfortunately I have no idea why it behaves this way. I would not except this code to work nor produce "null" as you observe. Someone who have a lot of experience with static fields initialization may be needed to solve your puzzle. Note that usage of static fields is generally frown upon most people don't have significant experience with such cases.

Comment: _template will always be null! its never been set.  you need to call SetDocTemplateProvider() to set it.  Remember static variables are initialised once only and at the start.

Comment: initialization of `_docTemplateProvider` inside a static ctor might also help.

Answer (score 1):

It is null because it is has never been set. You have two Void methods that set the _docTemplateProvider variable, so you need to call them first, like the example code below

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        DocumentTemplateProvider.SetDocTemplateProvider<Test>();
        //OR
        DocumentTemplateProvider.SetdocTemplateProvider(() => new Test());

        IDocumentTemplateProvider _template = DocumentTemplateProvider.TemplateProvider;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static class DocumentTemplateProvider
    {
        private static Func<IDocumentTemplateProvider> _docTemplateProvider;

        public static void SetdocTemplateProvider(Func<IDocumentTemplateProvider> docTemplateProvider)
        {
            _docTemplateProvider = docTemplateProvider;
        }

        public static void SetDocTemplateProvider<T>() where T : IDocumentTemplateProvider, new()
        {
            _docTemplateProvider = () => new T();
        }

        public static IDocumentTemplateProvider TemplateProvider
        {
            get { return _docTemplateProvider(); }
        }
    }
}

internal interface IDocumentTemplateProvider
{
}

public class Test : IDocumentTemplateProvider
{
}
```

Comment: Note that `_template` in OP's code is `public static readonly IDocumentTemplateProvider  _template` which is about initialization of static fields and totally different from basic invocation of static method in Main... Whether it is what OP is actually asking is currently open question.

Comment: regardless, _template is never set isn't it?

Comment: Since it is static readonly field in OP's code it should be  initialized by runtime before first use - and initializer in that case is `DocumentTemplateProvider.TemplateProvider` (again static property referring to static field). I'd expect NRE (as `_docTemplateProvider` should be still `null` at that point), but somehow OP gets regular `null`.

Comment: I would expect it to be a null, until he calls SetdocTemplateProvider(); in the ctor or before doing a return _docTemplateProvider() check if its null;

Comment: `_docTemplateProvider` is indeed `null`, but `TemplateProvider` *invokes* delegate - so `_docTemplateProvider()` should throw in my understanding as I don't see any `null` checks in the code...